# Xamarin.Forms DataTemplateSelector doesnt work on iOS (Constructor not called)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am inflating a data template selector like so:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"></local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0"   >

                <abstractions:CarouselViewControl VerticalOptions="Start"  x:Name="carouselview" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />

            </Grid>
```

The Code looks like this:

```
    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {
        Layout1 = new DataTemplate(typeof(CV_CarouselView_ShowPics));
        Layout2 = new DataTemplate(typeof(CV_VideoPlayer));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        FullAdType cell = (FullAdType)item;

        if(cell != null && cell.hasVideo )
        {

            return Layout2; // get video layout 

        }

        else
            return Layout1;

    }
```

But neither of the data template selectors constructors is called on iOS but on Android, it works just fine.

What is the issue here?

Thank you

Comment: The `DataTemplate ` should be defined in xaml , we don't need template selectors constructors , check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector .

Comment: It is however called in android and on iOS nothing is shown...

Answer (score 0):

We often define the `DataTemplate`  in xaml ,[check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime) .

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AmericanMonkeyTemplate">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherMonkeyTemplate">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <controls:MonkeyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MonkeySelector"
                                             AmericanMonkey="{StaticResource AmericanMonkeyTemplate}"
                                             OtherMonkey="{StaticResource OtherMonkeyTemplate}" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MonkeySelector}" />
```

---

However , if you want to initialize DataTemplate in code behind, you can create them in data template selector constructor .

```
public PersonDataTemplateSelector()
        {
            ValidTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=> {

                var grid = new Grid();

                var nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
                nameLabel.TextColor = Color.Green;
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);

                return grid ;
            });

            InvalidTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {

                var grid = new Grid();

                var nameLabel = new Label {  };
                nameLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);

                return grid ;
            });

        }
```

Comment: Even when I do that, ios does not return anythingl On select Template is never called either

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic, minimal project to us for test ? Since it works fine on side , the constructor is called as expected.

Comment: I found the issue: This:  <abstractions:CarouselViewControl should just be <Carouselview ...

Comment: Tha's fine, if you have any other problem please let me know.